# How to set different prices for bundle items for different websites, programmatically?

Tags: magento-1, price, bundled-product, programmatically

Say, now I have 2 websites (A & B) created.
And then I have created two simple products (Product X & Y), and a bundle product Z, with X & Y set as its bundled items.

How could I set the price for these bundled items under websites A & B, programmatically?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code or clear issues you're running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to add those prices in this way:

But I'm not sure if it is a "good" way to do so.

```
$product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load({{product_id}});
$writer = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('bundle/selection_price');
$values = array(
  'selection_id' => {{selection_id}},
  'website_id'   => {{website_id}},
  'selection_price_type' => 0,
  'selection_price_value' => {{price}}
);
$writer->insertOnDuplicate(
  $table,
  $values,
  array('selection_price_type', 'selection_price_value')
);
```